# Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'. Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin. - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm Getting it when I **run the application** and if I click "**Sync Project with Gradle Files.**"

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.application'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
> > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.
> > com/android/build/api/dsl/extension/AppExtension

Parts of My App/build.grade:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
.....
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
...
    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.manshore.mosaic_doctors"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

App/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip
```

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
....
```

android/gradle/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

in Files/Settings Gradle is set to **corrretto-11**

I have tried changing

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

to multiple versions and tried to change:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip
```

to multiple versions and tried all solutions on Stackoverflow and web and nothing worked
also, I tried to change java sdk to multiple versions.